# Filtrar un DataFrame usando una lista

Tags: python, lista, pandas

Si poseo el siguiente dataframe

```
  a,b,c
0 2,3,8
1 5,6,5
2 7,8,7
```

Quisiera filtrar las filas, pero usando una lista creada previamente. Utilice algo así:

```
num=[2,5]
df=df[df['a'] in num]
```

Quisiera obtener el siguiente resultado:

```
  a,b,c
0 2,3,8
1 5,6,5
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), 
a.any() or a.all().
```

Obviamente, quiero realizar esto con un dataframe con datos más complejo como string y deseo filtrar las filas del dataframe por los elementos de una columna según si estos pertenecen a una lista obtenida  por un proceso previo.

Saludos y de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las condiciones que puedes poner entre corchetes no son expresiones "normales" de python. Las expresiones de python operan entre datos escalares (no entre series o vectores). Algunos operadores de comparación están redefinidos (sobrecargados) para que funcionen con series pandas, como el operador `==`, y por eso lo siguiente funciona:

```
>>> df[df['a']==2]
```

`df['a']` da como resultado una `Series` panda con los valores de la columna "a". En principio no podemos comparar una columna entera con el número 2, que es lo que parece que estamos haciendo. Lo que ocurre es que el tipo `Series` tiene redefinido su operador de comparación de modo que cuando lo comparas con un escalar (el 2), hace en realidad una operación "vectorial", comparando todos los elementos de la columna con 2 y retornando una `Series` de booleanos (con `True` en los casos en que fue cierta).

Para poder implementar ese truco, Pandas define la función `Series.__eq__()`, que es lo que Python llamará cuando encuentre una comparación `==` entre una `Series` y otra cosa.

No todos los operadores Python pueden sobrecargarse de la misma forma. El operador `in` que intentas usar, por ejemplo, no se puede. No hay un método "mágico" (equivalente al `__eq__()` de antes) para el operador `in`.

Así que Pandas se ve obligado a usar otra sintaxis aquí. El método que define para hacer ese tipo de comparaciones es `Series.isin(conjunto)`, pero este 
método hay que invocarlo de forma explícita (ej: `df[df['a'].isin([2,3])`) y la sintaxis `df[df['a'] in [2,3])` no funciona.

Por tanto tu ejemplo se resuelve así:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[2,5,7], b=[3,6,8], c=[8,5,7]))
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c
0  2  3  8
1  5  6  5
2  7  8  7

>>> num=[2,5]
>>> df=df[df['a'].isin(num)]
>>> print(df)
   a  b  c
0  2  3  8
1  5  6  5
```

**Ampliación**

Ya que ha salido este tema, y sólo por afán completista, mencionaré el por qué de la extraña sintaxis de las expresiones booleanas dentro de los corchetes a la hora de seleccionar filas en Pandas.

Si queremos por ejemplo filtrar las filas en las que la columna "a" vale 2 **y** la columna "b" vale 3, quizás estaríamos tentados de escribir:

```
>>> df[df['a']==2 and df['b']==3]
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

¿Por qué no ha funcionado? Como expliqué antes `df['a']==2` es una operación vectorizada que en realidad está ejecutando `df['a'].__eq__(2)` y que retorna una `Series` que en este caso tendría los valores `True`, `False`, `False`, indicando qué filas cumplen la condición. Análogamente `df['b']==3` ejecuta `df['b'].__eq__(3)` que da como resultado la serie `True`, `False`, `False`, y ahora queremos hacer el `and` booleano entre ambas series.

Por desgracia el operador `and` sólo funciona cuando a su izquierda y derecha tenemos valores booleanos (o que puedan interpretarse como booleanos).  Pero lo que tenemos en este caso a izquierda y derecha del `and` son series. ¿Cuál es el valor booleano de una serie como `True`, `False`, `False`? A diferencia de una lista python que se considera `False` si está vacía o `True` si no, las series Pandas no tienen un valor de verdad definido. Por tanto no pueden usarse como parte de expresiones booleanas. De hecho, el error nos está diciendo precisamente eso: *The truth value of a Series is ambiguous*.

En cambio esta otra sorprendente sintaxis *sí que funciona*:

```
>>> df[(df['a']==2) & (df['b']==3)]
   a  b  c
0  2  3  8
```

He tenido que cambiar `and` por `&` y poner entre paréntesis cada una de las condiciones `==` ¿por qué ahora sí funciona?

Es un truco pandas. El operador `and` (como pasaba con `in`) no puede sobrecargarse para darle otro significado (como sí podemos hacer con `==` que puedo reimplementar en el método `__eq__()`. Pero el operador `&` sí que se puede sobrecargar, implementando el método `Series.__and__()`.

Normalmente el operador `&` realiza la operación AND "bit a bit" entre sus dos operandos, pero Pandas lo ha sobrecargado para que realice la operación booleana `and` elemento a elemento entre dos series.

Es decir, la expresión:

```
(df['a']==2) & (df['b']==3)
```

es evaluada por python como:

```
(df['a'].__eq__(2)).__and__(df['b'].__eq__(3))
```

que hace la "magia" que queríamos.

Análogamente '|' es implementado en `Series.__or__()` y `~` es implementado en `Series.__not__`, y junto con que `<` se implementa en `Series.__lt__()`, etc. esto nos permite escribir cosas como:

```
df[(df['a']>2) | ~(df['b']>3)]
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Por cierto, otra forma alternativa si nuestro amor por  `in` es muy grande  XD es usando `DataFrame.query`,  `df = df.query('a in @num')`, pero no ofrece ninguna ventaja en este caso.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me aclaraste muchas cosas que estaba pasando por alto

Comment: @JuanIgnacio He completado la respuesta con otros operadores mágicos relacionados con expresiones booleanas